# Querying transactions in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I found a query in: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-common/test/data/zip/test-archive/queries.qry that shows an ability to query particular transactions.  I thought I'd give this a try, but I don't ever get any results back.  Here's what I have defined:

my .cto file:

```
namespace org.my.namespace

transaction PlaceOrder {
  o String item
  o Integer quantity
  --> Company requester
  --> Company supplier
}
```

my queries.qry file:

```
query PlaceOrderTransactions {
  description: "select transactions"
  statement:
      SELECT org.my.namespace.PlaceOrder
}
```

I can run the PlaceOrder transaction from the swagger api of the Composer REST Server.  My transactions writes out Orders, and I can see them along with the transactions (/system/transactions endpoint).  When I try to run my query (from under named queries), I don't get anything back.  Am I missing something obvious?  Is there another way to query the transactions that I should be using?

Answer (score 3):

Is it the full CTO file you have defined (or are you just showing a segment of CTO file?)

The `transaction` structure you defined in CTO is just a “input param payload structure” you gonna pass for the transaction processor (a js under `${project-root}/lib)`. And that transaction processor should change some states of an `asset` defined in CTO, which resulted by invoking such transaction processor.

The `query.qry` then should query against the asset instead. For composer recorded transaction history, you can refer to a WIP feature named as Historian.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/historian.html

Comment: I'm just showing a segment of the file.  I've actually done the work that you've mentioned about having the transaction change state and then querying the asset.  When I saw the transaction query in somebody else's CTO file, I got curious.  I think your historian reference is what I'm looking for.